# ConfigurationManager - get section inside of section group

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm trying to do something very simple: Read the contents of a section that is part of a section group in my App.config file.

This should be easy - right?

Turns out I've been trying to do this for an hour, tons of googling and debugging, and I just can't do it. When I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection`, it returns `null` - this only works when the desired section is not part of a section group.

All I've found so far is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup?view=netframework-4.8) page by Microsoft that suggests parsing the XML myself. Seriously!?!?

I hope someone can help me, because right now this just makes me wanna hack it together with YAML in 5 minutes and never use .NET in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this question is quite old but I wanted to submit the correct answer for it.

When you are attempting to read the values from a section in the App.config or Web.config of your probject but that section is within a Section Group, you can access those values as a key/value pair as stated in the previous answer. But you instead of passing in just the section name, you must pass in a string formatted as {SectionGroupName}/{SectionName} like this:

```
var section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SectionGroupName/SectionName");
var value = section["key"];
```

Comment: I forgot even having asked this question. Thank you for taking the time! Unfortunately, it turned out I really never used .NET in the future :D but hey anyway thanks for this good answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able access them as key/value pairs:

```
NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SectionName");
string userName = section["userName"];
```

Try casting and see if you get the same result.
If not the Linq to XML answer is always a good fallback.

```
var section = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile).Root.Element("SectionName");

var userName= (string)section.Element("SomeElement").Elements("add")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("key") == "userName")
    .Single().Attribute("value");
```